# Sort all files in a folder independently, with an output file for each

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, cygwin, sorting

I have several folders that contain numerous text files, ranging from tens to 100s. These text files are simple databases containing millions of lines, with each line containing a single record. However, the records in them are unsorted and contain many duplicates. I'd like to to sort and de-duplicate them all individually (i.e. independently of each other), but to my understanding, `sort` can only produce a concatenated output of all input files - that is, even if given multiple files, it will only produce one output file containing the combined results of all those files.

**How can I sort all files in the current folder to produce an individually sorted output file for each one**? I'd also like for the output files to be outputted to a subfolder within the current directory. A `for` loop is the obvious solution to me, but I'm asking here in case there's some simpler way to do this with `sort` that I've not come across or missed. My `bash` knowledge is also very lacking, so if a `for` loop *is* the simplest solution, I'd appreciate someone providing the best way to go about that rather than me spending many days hacking something together that would still fall short of what I want to do.

Comment: `sort -u` provides a single record list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with `for`. Even if there is "some simpler way to do this with `sort`" (but I don't think so), this is also quite simple:

```
# cd to the directory you want to process

mkdir sorted    
for file in *; 
do
   printf 'Processing %s\n' "$file"
   [ -f "$file" ] && sort -u "$file" > "./sorted/$file"
done
```

Notes:

- `for file in *` doesn't process files in subdirectories.
- `printf` is only to report progress. In fact it should be placed after `[ ... ]` (see below) but I don't want to overcomplicate the code. You can just remove the `printf` line, if you want the whole thing to be silent.
- `[ -f "$file" ]` checks if `$file` is a regular file. With the most general pattern (i.e. `*`) we need this condition at least to avoid running `sort` with the `sorted` directory as an argument (this would throw an error, harmless but non-elegant). Most likely this test won't be needed if you use a more specific glob like `*.txt` or `*.db` instead of `*` (e.g. to skip a stray `desktop.ini` file that shouldn't be processed). In this case you can omit `[ ... ] &&` and start the line with `sort` (leaving the line intact shouldn't hurt though).
- `sort` supports various options and you may want to use some of them, depending on how you need to sort.
- `sort -u` de-duplicates entries right after sorting them, and when already using `sort` is a less redundant alternative to using the `uniq` command.

If you needed to pick files according to conditions more complex than a simple glob, `find` might be better to start with. For your current task `for` should be fine.

Comment: This looks perfect, thank you so much. There is a part of the code that I'm a little confused on - where does the `[ -f "$file" ]` come from? That is, what command does the `-f` parameter belong to, and what exactly do the square brackets mean? I haven't seen that sort of syntax used in a bash file before, at least not in this context.

Comment: Okay, I found my answer here that it's synonymous with the `test` command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036052/what-does-f-mea, but for clarification, what exactly does this mean? That `[ ... ]` is shorthand for the test command?

Comment: @Hashim See `help [` in Bash.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't give any information other than saying it's a synonym, so I suppose that's the only answer. There is one more thing - I've become accustomed to doing `LC_ALL=C sort` to make what usually be a ridiculously slow `sort` command a lot faster by limiting it to the default (US English) locale. Do you know of any way to incorporate that into your code above? Simply adding it before `sort` as normal results in a `syntax error near unexpected token &&`. It's not a major problem if it can't be done, but it would be nice to find out whether it can be.

Comment: Also, I hope you don't mind but I made some minor edits to the code that I feel make it slightly less redundant, feel free to revert them if there was a reason for the way you coded it originally.

Comment: @Hashim `[ -f "$file" ] && LC_ALL=C sort …` works for me on Debian.

Comment: Nevermind, I was being slightly dense. Had decided to take out the file test command but had forgotten what you said about starting the line with sort. That gave me the following: https://pastebin.com/hxs9xNBm. I suppose I assumed that the `&&` would chain on from the `printf` command just like it did with the file test command. Is there a reason this isn't the case?

Comment: @Hashim Yes. When the shell parses `printf`, it has no reason to look forward to the next line. When the shell encounters your `&&`, the line with `printf` has already been parsed and executed.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Sorry to keep bothering you with this but I promise this is the last question I'll ask for this piece of code. :P I've been trying to figure out how to modify the code in question to output the sorted file in the same directory, but with a `_sorted` suffix at the end of it. Is that a lot harder to do? I can't seem to find any help for it elsewhere hence why I'm still bothering you. So far I have `LC_ALL=C sort -u "$i" >> "./$i_sorted"`, but for some reason that stops with `Is a directory` errors even though it looks to me like a file and there is no such directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83138/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-hashim).